# Combining two DFAs into an NFA to recognize concatenation

Tags: automata

Suppose we have two separate DFAs that each recognize their own language. What is the most efficient way to combine these two DFAs into one NFA that recognizes the concatenation of both languages?

Comment: Add $\varepsilon$-transitions from each accepting state of the first one to the initial state of the second?

Comment: What is the start state? The start state of the first machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Diagram of concatenation of two NFAs]

To make an NFA for the concatenation of $A$ and $B$, put the states of $A$ and $B$ together.

Keep all the transitions of $A$ and of $B$, and 
add $\epsilon$-transitions from the final states of $A$ to the initial state  of $B$.

Make the initial state of the combined machine the same as the initial state of $A$.

Make the final states of the combined machine the same as the final states of $B$.

This construction probably appears in your book, as part of the proof that regular expressions are equivalent to NFAs. The proof must include a method for converting a regular expression of the form $AB$ to an NFA, given NFAs for regular expressions $A$ and $B$.  It certainly appears in the Hopcroft and Ullman book.

Answer (score 1):

Given DFAs $M'$ and $M''$ which recognise languages $L'$ and $L''$, consider the NFA $M$ defined as follows.

The states of $M$ are the union of those of $M'$ and $M''$; the initial state of $M'$ is an initial state of $M$, and if the empty word is accepted by $M'$ then the initial state of $M''$ is a second initial state of $M$.  The final states of $M$ are just those of $M''$.  We retain all the transitions in $M'$ and $M''$, and in addition, for any arrow leading to an accepting state in $M'$ we add a duplicate arrow leading to the initial state of $M''$.

I'll leave you to convince yourself that this works.

As to "most efficient", no real idea, but as we have taken only the states we had in the two given DFAs, it's pretty hard to imagine getting anything smaller in general.

Comment: How can M have two initial states?

Comment: I'm assuming that by NFA you mean "non-deterministic finite automaton"?  It can have as many initial states as you like.  (At least in the definition I have always used, maybe your instructor does it differently.)  It's really no different from saying that you can have two or more transitions from the same state with the same label: an initial state is so to speak the target of an arrow "coming from nowhere".